# Passing db object to php class oop style does not work

Tags: php, database, oop, pdo

Simple classes  using oop php, trying to pass db object (from db class)  to another class ( category class ) so i can get the content from db .

> db class db.php

```
    class db {

    //put your code here
    private $hostname = "127.0.0.1";
    private $dbname = "php_oop_crud";
    private $username = "root";
    private $password = "";
    public $conn;
    public $status = 0;

    public function getConnection() {
        $this->conn = null;

        try {

            $this->conn = new PDO("mysql:host:$this->hostname;dbname=$this->dbname", $this->username, $this->password);
            // this return null if  unsccessfull
            $this->status = $this->conn->getAttribute(PDO::ATTR_CONNECTION_STATUS);

            if ($this->status) {
                echo "connected to db : " . $this->status;

                return $this->conn;
            }
        } catch (PDOException $ex) {
            echo "Can't connect to db " . $this->status;
            error_log("Ayman :: {{$ex->getMessage()}} - {{$ex->getFile()}} - {{$ex->getLine()}}");
            return $this->conn;
        }
    }

}
```

> pass db object to category class in index.php

```
// Create db connection pass it to product and category objects
$databaseConn =  new db();
$db = $databaseConn->getConnection();


// create object  and send database object to class 
// now we need to call the function who crearte tha actual connection getConnection();

$category= new category($db);

$category->read();
```

> category class category.php

```
<?php

class category {

    //put your code here
    private $databaseConn;
    private $tabel_name = 'categories';

    public $id;
    public $name;

    public function __construct($db) {
        $this->databaseConn = $db;
    }


    public function read() {

        $sql = 'SELECT * FROM  categories';
        $query = $this->databaseConn->prepare($sql);
        $isok = $query->execute();
        $row= $query->rowCount(); 

        echo "row : " . $row;
         var_dump($row);

        echo "isok : " . $isok;
         var_dump($isok);


        if ($isok) {
            echo "the red process is done and ok <br/> category table";
        } else {
            echo "Cant get category ";
            var_dump($isok);
        }


    }

}
```

> Now the  `var_dump($row)` and `var_dump($isok);` are always false , mean while I can connect successfully to db 
>   [image]

Comment: `execute()` returns `false` when there's an error. Add this after executing: `var_dump($isok->errorInfo());` to see more about it.

Comment: @ishegg ($isok) will be always boolean so if i so what you have suggest the error will be  "Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function errorInfo() on boolean"

Comment: You're right, I meant `var_dump($query->errorInfo());`

Comment: array (size=3)
  0 => string '3D000' (length=5)
  1 => int 1046
  2 => string 'No database selected' (length=20)

?

Comment: How come "No database selected'" ?

Comment: Your PDO data source is misconstrued. Change it for this: `$this->conn = new PDO("mysql:host=".$this->hostname.";dbname=".$this->dbname, $this->username, $this->password);`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154915/discussion-between-mvrk-and-ishegg).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Credit for  @ishegg , be careful when you construct your PDO .

// this will NOT work

```
$this->conn = new PDO("mysql:host:$this->hostname;dbname=$this->dbname", $this->username, $this->password);
```

// this will Work

```
$this->conn = new PDO("mysql:host=".$this->hostname.";dbname=".$this->dbname, $this->username, $this->password);
```

[image]

Comment: To clarify: the problem was not how you concatenated the variables, but the misplaced `:` instead of `=`. This would have worked just as well: `$this->conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$this->hostname;dbname=$this->dbname", $this->username, $this->password);`. I just did it like that because it's clearer.